# Изучение мавен для работы в командной строке

Tags: java, maven

Может кто порекомендовать ресурсы по изучению мавен как утилиты терминала? Попадавшиеся мне туториалы были в виде "нажмите это, нажмите то... и все это только в конкретной IDE"

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html